# Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub Error while connecting to the Azure IOT hub from JMeter using JMXMon Sample Collector

Tags: azure, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, azure-load-testing

I am trying to plot JMX performance metrics for my test plan while performing load test on sending telemetry data to the azure IOT hub .

I referred following document to pull out performance metric
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/

But facing the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCJgL.png)

I have tried altering URL as mentioned here :-
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://YOURHOST:6969/jmxrmi or

service:jmx:rmi://YOURHOST:JMX_PORT/jndi/rmi://YOURHOST:JMX_PORT/jmxrmi

service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://**HUBNAME**.azure-devices.net:6969/jmxrmi
service:jmx:rmi://**HUBNAME**.azure-devices.net:8883/jndi/rmi://DIoT-HSync-IoTHub.azure-devices.net:8883/jmxrmi

How to configure this ?
Thanks In Advance :)

How to use JMXMon Sample Collector sampler while connecting to the azure IOT hub to pull JMX performance metrics

Answer (score 0):

By default Java applications don't expose JMX RMI endpoints, you need to start RMI server by providing the following properties to your Java application arguments:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6969
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6969
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Be informed that above configuration is **very** insecure and it means that literally anyone can connect to your application and do potentially harmful stuff so it worth enabling SSL and authentication before proceeding.

More information: [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html)

Before trying to use JMXMon Samples Collector you might want to try connecting to the RMI endpoint via [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

If you cannot amend your application startup configuration you can take a look at the following alternatives:

- [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
- [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon)